# zsh: How can I escape each word separately?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, escape-characters

How can the following list of commands can be quoted separately?

```
s="cp                                                  
mkdir
[[
mv
rm"

quoted_s= ????
```

This should be the output of `echo $quoted_s`:

```
cp                                                  
mkdir
\[\[
mv
rm
```

Using `${(q)s}` or `${(qq)s}` quotes them together:

```
$ echo ${(qq)s}
'cp
mkdir
[[
mv
rm'
```

Comment: What are you doing with that multi-line string? Is that supposed to be a list of values that are somewhat separate, or is it actually a single string? If the former, you might want to consider using an array instead.

Comment: Good point :-) It is used for completion - probably a better method exists.  Please see https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr-node-client/blob/master/bin/completion/zsh/_tldr . Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you could use the `b` expansion flag. From `info zsh flag` or `man zshexpn`:

```
   b      Quote with backslashes only characters that are special to  pat‐
          tern  matching.
```

So given

```
~ % print -r -- $s
cp
mkdir
[[
mv
rm
```

then

```
~ % print -r -- ${(b)s}
cp
mkdir
\[\[
mv
rm
```

More generally, you could split on newlines, apply `q` to the result, and re-join:

```
~ % print -r -- ${(F)${(qf)s}}
cp
mkdir
\[\[
mv
rm
```

or with a csh-style postfix modifier

```
~ % print -r -- ${(F)${(f)s}:q}
cp
mkdir
\[\[
mv
rm
```

or even (letting `print` add back the newlines)

```
% print -rC1 -- ${(qf)s}
cp
mkdir
\[\[
mv
rm
```

(`-C1` to print on `1` `C`olumn has the advantage over `-l` that if there's no argument, nothing is printed as opposed to one empty line).

Note that the `b`, `q`, `qq`, `qqq`, `qqqq`, `q-`, `q+` flags and `:q` modifiers produce different kinds of quoting, pick the one that suits you best for your particular use case.

Whatever you do don't forget the `--`. Omitting it introduces arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities, the worst kind of vulnerability.